# How to delete duplicated lists from main list [python]

Tags: python, list, arraylist, duplicates

i want to delete duplicated lists from main list

input : `[['a','b'],['c','f'],['a','b'],['d','f']]`

output: `[['a','b'],['c','f'],['d','f']]`

Comment: `list(set(tuple(i) for i in l))`

Comment: `set(map(tuple, l))`

Comment: @ajay that would return a list of tuples, the OP wants to keep them as lists.

Comment: @anonymous that would return a *set* of tuples, the OP wants a list of lists as output.

Comment: @costaparas if resultant is really needed as list of lists, then it could be get as `list(map(list, set(map(tuple, l))))`. However, if the need is to just iterate, i don't think that really necessary. `set(map(tuple, l))` will return set of tuples but could be used similar to other iterables

Comment: @anonymous Similar, but not the same. A set has very different properties than a list. We don't know the context the OP is using this data, so its not justified to convert it to some different type or format and makes more sense to keep it in its original format, unless we have more information.

Comment: Just to add, however, as an iterator, there is no difference between a list of tuples and a list of lists. Otherwise, ofcourse, there are differences.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try simply using set after creating each element as an immutable object.

```
out = list(set([tuple(i) for i in a]))
out
```

```
[('d', 'f'), ('a', 'b'), ('c', 'f')]
```

---

If you want to convert it back to list of lists -

```
list(map(list, out))
```

```
[['d', 'f'], ['a', 'b'], ['c', 'f']]
```

Answer (score 1):

Use list comprehension on the list obtained after getting the unique list of tuples:

```
x = [['a','b'],['c','f'],['a','b'],['d','f']]
x = [list(x) for x in set(map(tuple, x))]
print(x)

Output:

[['a', 'b'], ['d', 'f'], ['c', 'f']]
```